# OpenVPN Server and client are connected, but unable to ping server from client and vice versa

Tags: openvpn

I am trying to set up OpenVPN server in Windows 7 system located in my office and Windows 10 system in my home as client. The server and client are connected, but unable ping the server from client and client from server.

Here are my config files.
Could somebody help to resolve the issue?

**Server config file**

```
dev-node "ServerVPN"
mode server
port 34867
proto tcp4-server
dev tun
tls-server
tls-auth "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\ta.key" 0
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\ServerVPN.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\ServerVPN.key"
dh "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\dh2048.pem"
client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
client-config-dir "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config"
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
verb 3
route-delay 5
route-method exe
push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0"
route 192.168.182.0 255.255.255.0
```

**CCD** - 
**ClientVPN**

```
ifconfig-push 10.8.0.3 10.8.0.4
i route 192.168.182.0 255.255.255.0
```

**Configuration in Client system**

```
remote XXX.XX.XXX.XX
client
port 34867
proto tcp4-client
dev tun
tls-client
tls-auth "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ta.key" 1
remote-cert-tls server
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ClientVPN.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ClientVPN.key"
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
auth-nocache
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
mute 20
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ifconfig-push 10.8.0.6 10.8.0.5
```

You might also need to do:

```
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0 nopool
ifconfig-pool 10.8.0.8 10.8.0.251
```

See [this](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/273-qifconfig-poolq-option-use-a-30-subnet-4-private-ip-addresses-per-client-when-used-in-tun-mode) for details.

You may also have these *instead*:

```
ifconfig-push 10.8.0.2 255.255.255.0
```

```
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0 nopool
ifconfig-pool 10.8.0.3 10.8.0.254
```

Btw you might be having a typo here:

```
push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0"
route 192.168.182.0 255.255.255.0
```

(`0` vs `182`)

If that's the case you probably need to push the route with the `DEFAULT`  ccd instead of the server conf so that it won't be pushed to the client that "owns" it. I'm assuming this is a multi-client setup and the server isn't supposed to "own" `192.168.1.0/24` though.